# Background image won't display 100% if it is generated at random

Tags: php, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am making a website that has two background images, one of them is always the same i.e.:

```
background-image: url("../images/centre-image.jpg");
```

and the other is generated via php to show a background image at random:

```
    <?php
      $bg = array('large-top1.jpg', 'large-top2.jpg', 'large-top3.jpg', 'large-top4.jpg', 'large-top5.jpg', ); // array of filenames

      $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
      $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
    ?>

<img src="images/background-images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>" class="bg">
```

Making the first background the full size of the DIV no matter what size of the screen was easy enough:

```
div.centre-options {
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

however if I try to add similar CSS to the random generated image it doesn't work (just shows it at its full jpg size and then repeats) and not sure show to solve the problem.

Comment: css couldn't care less how the image `src` attribute is generated. it will **NEVER** see php code or know that it's php output.

Comment: What's the CSS for the .bg class?

Comment: What's the CSS for img.bg class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can tell the image generated isn't set as a background but as a image to display, therefore you can't apply background styling to it.

There is 2 things you can do either apply styling directly to the image tag i.e.

```
img.bg{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

or alternatively create an element and add the generated image to it's styling 
would look somthing like this:

```
 <?php
      $bg = array('large-top1.jpg', 'large-top2.jpg', 'large-top3.jpg', 'large-top4.jpg', 'large-top5.jpg', ); // array of filenames

      $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
      $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
    ?>
<style>
div.bg{
background-image: url("images/background-images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>");
background-size: 100% auto;
}
</style>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Preferable put the styling between the head tags

Comment: Thank you! The problem was I first tried to add the background image in the css file and it didnt understand the php echo. So I put it in the div itself i.e. <div class="bg" style="background-image: url>. By doing that it was ignoring the background size property that I had put in the css file